# Data prepration for logistic regression : Value either "not available" or a "year"

Tags: logistic-regression, missing-data

I have some data of houses that have been renovated.

In my data there is one column (among others) that captures this information.

It is either "-1" if there has not been yet any renovation, or the information is the year of renovation like "1995" or "2008".

I would like to apply logistic regression.

However, I do not know how to treat this value.

IMHO it looks like a missing value although it is not a missing information.

So, does anybody have an idea how to put these (unordered) values into relation to the ordered years?

On alternative I could think of is binning the information. Like 1990-1995, 1996-2000,...2016-2019.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you change value of "year of renovation" to be same "year of construction" for houses that have not been renovated; does it makes sense for this problem ?

Comment: Yeah, this is a of course a good idea and it also makes sense. In my case this is however, not applicable. Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 4):

First use a binary 0 (no renovation) and 1 (renovation) which works perfect with logistic regression.

Using the exact date is a bad practice. It guides the model in the direction of **over-fitting** on specific dates. For example, a pattern from 2006 would be specific to that year and would not help the future years. As an alternative, binning on larger spans like 5 years, 10 years (depends on the context) seems as an improvement. For example:

bins = [1990, 2000], [2000, 2010], [2010, 2020]
[1990, 2000] $\rightarrow$ (1, 0, 0)
[2000, 2010] $\rightarrow$ (0, 1, 0)
[2010, 2020] $\rightarrow$ (0, 0, 1)

This approach also has a tendency to over-fit but over a larger time span. Also note that, this way, your model always has an **expiration date**, since if we pass the last bin in 2021, there is no bin to cover the year. And if we include [2020, 2030] now, there is no data to learn about this bin. And using [2020, forever] is equally useless for future.

I suggest using the **age** of construction and renovation which are generalizable. A 5 years old house in 2000 could help us infer about a 5 years old house in 2010, 2020, or 2030. For houses with no renovation, age could be set to -1, which works fine with logistic regression (experiment with 0 too). So as a final example:

```
renovation     (has renovation, renovation age)
-1             (0, -1)
2010 in 2019   (1, 9)
```

Note that repetitive time features are OK. For example, "Spring", "Monday", or "8:00PM", etc.

Comment: Great advice. Thanks for this help. Makes sense :)